# Gmail to Google Sheets Script Help

Tags: google-sheets, gmail, google-apps-script

I'm new to Google Scripts and struggling to optimize a code I've found.

I used [this base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890847/google-apps-scripts-extract-data-from-gmail-into-a-spreadsheet) to extract the emails from Gmail and feed them into a Google Sheet, and that's working fine.

However, I would like to either extract what is in the "getPlainBody()" String to another column or find some other way to separate out specific data from the body of the email.

I was trying to use (\d+(?:.\d{2}) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862827/how-does-one-find-the-currency-value-in-a-string) to automatically record times, but I'm not sure where to input the function into my overall code (or if I need a separate code).

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. _or find some other way to separate out specific data from the body of the email._ You'll need to be provide much more specific information about the content and structure of the body of the email as well as any part that you want to separate out.

Answer (score 1):

*I would like to either extract what is in the "getPlainBody()" String to another column*

Inside your loop, add:

`var body = messages[j].getPlainBody();`

then modify the `appendrow()` to include the body.

`ss.appendRow([msg, sub, dat, body])`